# kernel of a projection is a inclusion.

Tags: category-theory

**Lemma** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. If $\pi_{i}: X_{1} \Pi X_{2} \longrightarrow X_{i}$ and $\mu_{i}: X_{i} \longrightarrow X_{1} \Pi X_{2}$ are, respectively, the projections and inclusions of the product $X_{1} \Pi X_{2}$, then $\ker(\pi_{2}) = \mu_{1}$.

---

[*The definition of kernel that I'm using is the following:
$\beta: P \longrightarrow A$ is a kernel of $\alpha: A \longrightarrow B$ if $\alpha \beta = 0$ and for all $\beta^{\prime}: P^{\prime} \longrightarrow A$ s.t. $\alpha \beta^{\prime}=0$, there exists a unique $\lambda: P^{\prime} \longrightarrow P$ such that $\beta \lambda = \beta^{\prime}$.*]

Here's my attempt: suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ has a null object. Then the kernel is given by the pullback

[$\hskip3in$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjxO7.png)

For the product we'll have the following diagram:

[$\hskip2.5in$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT1CB.png)

All I have to do is show that the second diagram is a pullback, i.e., 
$\pi_{2} \mu_{1} = 0 $ (for the commutativity of the diagram) and for all $u: C \longrightarrow X_{1} \Pi X_{2}$ such that $\pi_{2} u = 0$, then there exists a unique $\gamma: C \longrightarrow X_{1}$ s.t. $\mu_{1} \gamma = u$.

Am I correct?

Thanks for the help :]~

Comment: It seems like you want to restrict to Abelian or at least additive categories. Also, you can format (simple) commutative diagrams with AMScd: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, and works in any pointed category as soon as the product $X_1\times X_2$ exists. Here's a hint to finish the proof : consider the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}X_1 @>>> 0 \\
@V{\mu_1}VV @VVV \\
X_1\times X_2 @>>{\pi_2}> X_2 \\
@V{\pi_1}VV @VVV \\
X_1 @>>> 0\end{CD}
and use the properties of pullback squares.